# How to configure a project to sync with existing git repository

Tags: git, github, configure

I was working on a git project on a laptop, but due to some technical issue I could not proceed with the same laptop. Till the repairing I worked on QA server directly, where git access was restricted earlier. 
   But later I got message that I could not use my old laptop anymore therefore to commit all my new code from QA server, I installed git there. As the QA Server have lots of configurations in place, so can not easily move the code somewhere else.
The issue is I'm not getting how can I configure git in same directory so that it should get synced with git repository.

Comment: If I understand this correctly: 1) You moved your git repository to the QA Server? Now you want to access the git repo from your new laptop? Correct? Surely, git clone <git repo>?

Comment: @Technophobe01 - No, not like that. Wanted to push a bare directory containing some code with existing remote git repositry in a separate branch.

Comment: You want to create a new remote branch and add the code to it from your laptop?

Comment: @Technophobe01: Much likely but my code don't have git configured. And not getting how to configure git in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution worked for me.

```
git init
git remote add origin ssh://...
git fetch
git add .
git checkout branch_I_want
```